# Cloudformation Template Generation Tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-lambda, pycharm, aws-cloudformation

I am looking for good tools to help me build Cloudformation templates locally and upload them once done. Your suggestions will be much appreciated. I am using pycharm.

Comment: You mean something like Terraform or CDK?

Comment: You want to generated them from existing resources?

Comment: I looked into Terraform and it seems like it will do what it takes.  Thanks.